# is there a way to set caret height in contenteditable div in html

Tags: html, css, caret

I need to deal with language like Myanmar, its characters are very much larger compare to other language like English. since then its line-height calculated by browser is even more large, that parts of the caret is out of the div border.

So I need a way to cause the caret to hold to its height unchanged from language to language. like you have Myanmar and English in same line, and the caret will hold on to 50px while moving from the left to the right. Or you can say that I'm trying to find a way to disable the browser's default behavior of calculating the height of the caret.

by the way, this only deal with opera presto, it's well performed on chrome or webkit.

Comment: show your work or code

Comment: Could you please put your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @IamRaviteja Finally I decide to abandon contenteditable div. I make the div a pure div and use a 1px width child div with a blinking animation to simulate the browser's caret, thus I can control all the style of the child div, and so is the "caret". Sorry about the source code, since the source is too large and its almost impossible to collect pieces of a working page to a simple html file. I will paste my css solution downstairs.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think I get the final perfect solution, but it's really a way to solve this problem somehow.

I use a child div with a blinking animation to simulate the browser's caret, and make the father div a pure div. here is the css code.

Here is the Github project which I think help me a lot.
https://gist.github.com/navinpai/2902229

```
.cursor {
    width: 1px;
    height: 80px;

    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30px;

    animation-name: see_likes;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-delay: 0s;

    -o-animation-name: see_likes;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes see_likes {
    0%   { background: #0a0 }
    47%  { background: #090 }
    50%  { background: transparent }
    97%  { background: transparent }
    100% { background: #090 }
}

@-o-keyframes see_likes {
    0%   { background: #0a0 }
    47%  { background: #090 }
    50%  { background: transparent }
    97%  { background: transparent }
    100% { background: #090 }
}
```